# ASP.NET MVC4 to 5 Upgrade

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have had to take a very old project out of it's dusty box and upgrade it from 4 to 5 and I followed the guidance on the MS Site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and it all works perfect locally on my dev machine. Yep it works on my machine so ship it right....

Well No because I publish to the server and this is where the issues start as I keep getting errors saying:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the
>    element of the Web.config file is used only to target
>   version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example,
>   ''). The 'targetFramework'
>   attribute currently references a version that is later than the
>   installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target
>   version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the
>   .NET Framework.

I have checked that the Web.Config file has the Target set to 4.7.1 and on the server the current version is 4.7.2 so where am I going wrong.

The line in the Web.Config that is being referenced is:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
```

And at the bottom of the error page:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2106.0

I like my local machine too much to ship it to the cloud so someone please help.  I have been bashing my head against the desk for hours now and Google/Bing etc are not helpful.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: In the server you don't have the .Net version 4.7.1   use the link to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses but this site is hosted on a shared hosting platform so I can't install anything, but I checked and they have 4.7.2 installed.

I fixed the problem by removing the targetFramework from the compilation settings and worked a treat.

Old:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" />
```

New:

```
<compilation debug="true" />
```

Thanks for the help. Now onto the next issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install "Runtime" SDK on the server?

The runtime SDK for Framework 4.7.1 can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

If you haven't done it, try it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the .Net version in the hosting server just install the .Net version in the server.

[.Net 4.7.1 Offline Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116)